# Show only month labels on HighChart xAxis

Tags: highcharts, linechart, axis-labels

I have some list of dates as categories for xAxis.
Example of collection : `2018-01-01, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-10, 2018-01-17, 2018-01-29;`

I want to display on chart dates in format `MMM yy` (Jan 18)

So I've tried to group all this dates by this date format. As result I received only 1 item in collection which is logically. But on chart I saw labels like this 
`Jan 18, 1, 2, 3, 4`

[image]

How to "group" values on chart to display only month labels?

Example what I have now https://jsfiddle.net/phwgo4jz/7/

Comment: Can you add in your code?

Comment: @Codeer, Hi! Give me few minutes. I will try to transwer it from C# to js :D. Yes, I do it on backend for export :(

Comment: I'm mostly looking for the data you are putting into the highcharts like the list of dates for the xAxis and the date formats  and the data points / the basic highcharts code.

Comment: @Codeer, I've tried to convert all dates to wanted format `MMM yy` and then select only distinct values. So in result I get `Jan 18` only

Comment: If I understand correctly, all datapoints are in January?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173340/discussion-between-demo-and-codeer).

Comment: So you wanna display only `Jan 2018` label in the example that you provided?

Comment: @KamilKulig, correct. In case I will have categories that are presented dates from another month like '2018-02-10' then on xAxis I want to see Jan 18 and Feb 18... Something like this

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `dateTimeLabelFormats` option of xAxis to format the label. Or simply set the type of xAxis to `datetime`. Highcharts scales the axis and inserts appropriate labels as required.

Here is the highcharts documentation : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Also a sample codepen with similar functionality as your requirement. Have a look
https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/XYVyNR?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, it can be as solution for me... but I need some formula how correctly calculate this `pointInterval`.. cause labels on xAxis are calculated based on amount of points

Answer (score 0):

`categories` are basically just an information how to display labels and position ticks - the axis still behaves like a "normal" linear axis. Highcharts will fill the axis labels up with subsequent integers if you don't provide categories for all y positions.

You can use `xAxis.labels.formatter` to filter categories out:

```
  formatter: function() {
    return Number.isInteger(this.value) ? '' : this.value;
  }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ytoj9ng2/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: in case of multiple months, labels on xAxis are only the first ones

Comment: You can put logic responsible for handling that in `formatter` too. Here's a live demo with simplified version of it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9yxmw7zv/